# Magento 2 : How to Check Cart Items Satisfying Cart Price Rule Condition?

Tags: magento2, product, shopping-cart-price-rules, cart-items

In my module I have condition like cart price rule.
How to check item in cart satisfy condition or not.

Comment: Hi. Did you find some solution?

Answer (score -1):

Create a coupon code with the condition you have with 0% discount just to test the condition satisfying or not.
Then you can apply that coupon code to your cart.

```
$quote = $this->cart->getQuote();
$quote->setCouponCode($couponcode)->collectTotals()->save();
$quoteCouponCode = $quote->getCouponCode();
if ($quoteCouponCode) {
   //condition is satisfied
   /*
    * your logic
    */    
}
$quote->setCouponCode('')->collectTotals()->save();
```